# SQL Null dates return 1900-01-01

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is part of my query:

```
IsNull(CONVERT(date, V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.ID50), '') AS 'actualFinish'
```

`V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.ID50` is a NULL and is a datetime column. So the results I get is 1900-01-01, what I am trying to do is return nothing just `' '` How would I accomplish this?

Comment: well, `' '` is not a date, so you should convert `ID50` to varchar instead

Comment: You can't return both a `DATE` and a `VARCHAR` datatype conditionally in the same column.  Either you convert the `DATE` to `VARCHAR`, or deal with a `NULL`.

Comment: @user979331 did my solution work?

Answer (score 4):

The mixing of types you have now is definitely a problem.

If you want to display an empty string for a null date you need convert the date into a short date time string not a date.   You can use the `convert` function to do that.  The last parameter accepts a style code so you can have it display just the date part.

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(8), V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.ID50, 101), '') AS 'actualFinish'
```

This will display the date in mm/dd/yy format if the column is not null, or an empty string if it is.

To see more about date to string conversions go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx.

Comment: If you only have one level of fallback you can also use the easier to spell [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) instead of `COALESCE`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I got into the habit of using `COALESCE` over `INSULL` and `CAST` over `CONVERT` because I occasionally work in other sql flavors where `ISNULL` and `CONVERT` isn't present because they aren't standard Sql.  In this case I had to use `CONVERT` for the style parameter as there is no equivalent parameter in `CAST`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` try using a `CASE` statement -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(date, V_CONSTAT_ACTUAL_DATES.ID50) END
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple ISNULL Nested CAST function can remove 1900-1-1 value if data is NULL

```
ISNULL(CAST(CAST(<<DateColumn>> AS DATE) AS Varchar),' ') [<<Date Column Name>>]
```